# Git new branch from working branch with commits only from working branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I've cloned repo and I have created new branch from master called working-branch. I was just doing local commits, I did not push anything yet. I want to actually first create new branch and after that push that branch to remote, but I want to take only commits history from working-branch. How to do that? I was reading about `git rebase` but I do not know if it's right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a new repo. A git repository contains all the comits from the start. But remember that when you push  a new branch you are  not copying all the previous commits, but simply pushing the ones which are new since you branched out and a reference to the last commit in that tree. This is the beauty of git branches, they are very lightweight because the basically are one line in a file containing the branch name and a commit id.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

If what you want is to add the commits from your working branch to master you could do the following:

```
git checkout working-branch 
git rebase master 
git checkout master 
git merge working-branch 
git push origin master
```

This will add your new commits to the tip of the master branch after resolving possible conflicts on your working branch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `working-branch` checked out.

```
git checkout -b new-branch
git push origin new-branch
```

Comment: That's not it, I still have every commit from master and working branch. .git is to big, with all stuff from master commits and my commits. I just want mine.